# unordered_set hash for type, whose comparison uses part of the type data

Tags: c++11, hash, unordered-set

I need `std::unordered_set` of pairs, whose first elements should be different.

Is it correct to hash only first element of pairs, as below?

```
using Pair = std::pair<int, int>;

struct Eq
{
    bool operator() ( Pair const& lhs,
                      Pair const& rhs ) const
    {
        return (lhs.first == rhs.first);
    }
};

struct Hash
{
    std::size_t operator() ( Pair const &p ) const
    {
        return std::hash<int>()( p.first );
    }
};

// No two pairs with same '.first'.
std::unordered_set<Pair, Hash, Eq> pairs;

for ( Pair const& p : ... )
{
    pairs.insert(p);
}
```

**In general, for `unordered_set<T>`**:

If equality functor for type `T` does not use part (some data members) of `T`, it makes sense not to use that part in `hash<T>` either.

Is this right?

Comment: Sounds good to me, as long as you can guarantee first elements will be distinct. What exactly bothers you?..

Comment: @Mikhail It is not guaranteed that all `.first` elements in the loop will be distinct.
The goal is: if multiple pairs have same `.first` element, keep the first pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, should work fine. From the documentation to [std::unordered_set::insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) (emphasis mine):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container **doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key**.

You clearly provided a predicate that says elements should be treated equivalent when their `first` fields match. And you specified a hash that makes sure equivalent elements end up in the same bucket. So this looks good to me.